# Control not rendering in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ascx

Before getting flack about using ascx controls in MVC let me preface that this is not what I would like to do!  However the powers above me would like to continue to use the ascx control.

I started by using the following in my controller:

```
public ActionResult _CreditReporting(int id)
{
    return PartialView();
}

public static class myClass
{
    public static string GenerateHtmlFromYourControl(this HtmlHelper helper, string contId)
    {
        var credControl = new _person_creditreporting_control();

        credControl.ID = contId;

        var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());

        credControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        return htmlWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

and the following in my view

```
@using ds_iDMS.Controllers
    <div>
    @{
    Html.GenerateHtmlFromYourControl("_person_creditreporting_control.ascx");
    }
    </div>
```

Everything seems to be working properly and all the parameters are being passed etc.  The ascx page is not rendering however and I am not sure why

Comment: Have you looked at the raw html in your browser e.g. Chrome's developer tools? Is it valid html?

Comment: @NamelessOne yes in the developer tools it shows that it is valid.  If I navigate to the view manually the view comes up but does not render anything at all

Comment: When you go to the view what is inside the `div`? (With 'what' I mean html-wise)

Comment: I have posted the entire view.  I am trying to just use the control to become the view.

Comment: Your browser doesn't understand ASP, it reads HTML. The problem is in the HTML that is generated, that is why I am asking for that. I am asking what is inside that `div` in the generated HTML.

Comment: I think I just found the issue.  I didn't put any HTML in the View.  What I thought is that the HTML in the ASCX file would render with the command that I passed.  Am I wrong? (apparently yes but would you offer an explanation)

Comment: ASP generates HTML dynamically based on ascx pages or views, so what your browser will render is still pure HTML. My hunch is that you shouldn't be using curly brackets around your method call if you wants its return string written to your page, but I might be wrong. That is why I asked for the generated HTML. What I'd also try, is doing the call without any brackets. If you want a refresher on the razor syntax Google the quick reference by Phil Haack.

Comment: I think I will take a look at that reference.  When I do it without the curly braces '<div> @Html.GenerateHtmlFromYourControl("_person_creditreporting_control.ascx"); </div>' It still doesn't produce anything.  So I think I must be doing the razor wrong.  I will take a look at that reference and update if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the view to

```
@using ds_iDMS.Controllers
<div>
    @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateHtmlFromYourControl("_person_creditreporting_control.ascx"))
</div>
```

[Phil Haack has a good quick reference guide to different bits of the razor syntax.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) it might be a little outdated by now, but it is still a very useful overview.

Comment: You could also change your `GenerateHtmlFromYourControl` method to call `Raw` on `helper`, and then use `@Html.GenerateHtmlFromYourControl("_person_creditreporting_control.ascx")` in your view.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you for your help!